# Simple sitemap scraper, saving to .txt

Tags: python

Just a quick question, I am trying to create a simple spider that will access the sitemap.xml of a site and save the urls in a notepad, I have the code below but it only saves 1 of the URLs in the notepad.

It seems to print all of the information I need in the CMD but not in the txt

```
import urllib2 as ur
import re

f = ur.urlopen(u'http://www.site.co.uk/sitemap.xml')
res = f.readlines()
for d in res:
  data = re.findall('<loc>(http:\/\/.+)<\/loc>',d)
  for i in data:
    print i
    file = open("sitemapdata.txt", "w")
    file.write(i)
    file.close()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I posted this, I realised what went wrong. I accidentally left out `+'\n'` and needed to change: `file = open("sitemapdata.txt", "a")`

```
import urllib2 as ur
import re

f = ur.urlopen(u'http://www.site.co.uk/sitemap.xml')
res = f.readlines()
for d in res:
  data = re.findall('<loc>(http:\/\/.+)<\/loc>',d)
  for i in data:
    print i
    file = open("sitemapdata.txt", "a")
    file.write(i +'\n')
    file.close()
```